# How do I get Powerpoint to call my VBA subroutine in an animation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

What I ultimately want to do is `ShellExecute()` a command-line program every time a new slide appears in my PowerPoint slide show. I'm using Office 2003 PowerPoint.

I did the following:

1. Tools **>** Options **>** Security Options **>** Macro Security **>** Security Level = Medium
2. Tools **>** Options **>** Macro **>** VBA Editor:

   ```
   Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
     MsgBox ("OnSlideShowPageChange")
   End Sub
   ```
3. File **>** Save
4. Back to PowerPoint: <kbd>F5</kbd> (for Slide Show **>** View Show). *Did NOT see the message box*
5. Exit out of PowerPoint, reopen the .ppt file, <kbd>F5</kbd>) again. *Still don't see the message box*

**Question**: What am I missing? Why isn't `OnSlideShowPageChange` getting invoked when I run the slide show???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working just fine for me, using exactly your steps above. The only think I can think of is on step #2 above, you may have put the automacro `OnSlideShowPageChange` in a Class or UserForm. It should go into a Module (any module, any name). Or do you have other code in there that may be interfering, like are you also sinking the `SlideShowNextSlide` event?

Comment: Hi, Otaku - thank you very much.

It's working again.  I did the following:
1. Backed everything down to an "old" version of the file (originally created with PPT 2003, but I was juggling back and forth between 2003 and 2007!)
2. Re-added (from the "old", "virgin") file the snippet above
3. Added it to a module (NOT a class module or a form, per your advice)
... and it worked!

Thank you!

Comment: @paulsm4, may i ask you to have a look at this question on another topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116963/bangla-language-not-displayed-in-the-unicoded-csv-file ?