# How to save Unicode Bangla CSV from XLSX?

Tags: csv, unicode, export-to-csv

After citing [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116963/bengali-language-text-not-displayed-in-unicode-csv-file), I'm posting here. I have an Excell 2007 (`.xlsx`) file with Bangla Unicode characters and English characters as well, like:

```
+------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
| name | company | responsibilities | started from | added_by |
+------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
| আলম  | কোম্পানীর নাম |       কর্মযজ্ঞ ১     |  2013/01/01  |   2305   |
| স্মরণ  | কোম্পানীর ধাম |       কর্মযজ্ঞ ২     |  2013/02/01  |   2155   |
+------+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
```

I'm trying to save it into a *Comma-Separated Values* file - CSV (`.csv`). I've experience in creating and uploading CSV in English, but this time the problem is with the Unicode characters.

#### MISSION #1

**Procedures:** Save as » Other formats » CSV - Save.

**Result:** Renders Bangla characters as scrambled.

**Status:** ***Failed***

---

#### MISSION #2

**Procedures:** Save as » Other formats » Unicode Text - Save.
Created a Tab separated CSV file.
Opening the .txt file into Notepad++ or Dreamweaver, and Find-Replace "tab" with "comma".

**Result:** Nicely done. Except some English characters are generating boxes, just when the replacing took place!

**Status:** ***Failed***

---

- What can I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1 - Lengthy Process

Save as » Other formats » Unicode Text - Save.
Creating a Tab separated CSV file.
Open the `.txt` file in Notepad (*Notepad.exe*)
In notepad, File » Save as » Encoding : UTF-8 » (choose a different name) » Save
Open the file in Notepad++, Find&Replace the "tab" with "comma".
Save it.

**Done!**

*Courtesy: Thanks to Tahmina Akhtar*

### Solution #2 - Shortcut Process

Download and Install an AddIn for Excell 2007. **[This Article](http://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/excel_addin_to_work_with_unicode_csv/)** will assist you through the process.

Download the file from **[Here](http://blog.jaimon.co.uk/UnicodeCSV/setupfiles.zip)**. It will download an installer only. After downloading, click on the `Setup.exe`. It'll start downloading its necessary components. After a complete download, install the AddIn. The system will reboot completely. Reboot the PC. Let's the installation complete.

Open the .xlsx file in MS Excell 2007. You will find a new Ribbon saying: **Unicode CSV**. Click on it, and Save the file.

**Done!**

> **NOTE:**
> None of the processes is completely bug-free. So, try 'em or find your new one, and why not let us know too.

### Edit 2015-Aug-27

Wrote [a complete article in Bengali on how to upload Bengali content using PHP-MySQL](https://mayeenulislam.github.io/tuts/csv-bengali-import-php-mysql/). You can check out.